# Do two things meanwhile with RxJava

Tags: rx-java

I have to do two things meanwhile `A` and `B`.

- If `A` done, `B` terminates.
- If `B` done, wait until `A` done.
- If `A` done or `B` done, do same thing.

So how can I do it with `RxJava` ?

## EDIT

There is something I have forgotten.

- `A` and `B` are Observables in `RxJava1.x`. And if `A` has been done, B should be disposed.
- do same thing means same subscriber.

Comment: What types are A and B? What do you mean by B terminates, it gets disposed?

Comment: @akarnokd I just updated my question.

Comment: what does the phrase "do same thing" mean?